# Common object change in all component when one of them edit it

Tags: angular

I have :

**item.ts**

```
export interface IItem {
  name: string;
  isActive?: boolean;
}

const data: IItem[] = [
  {
    name: 'item1',
    isActive: true
  },
  {
    name: 'item2',
    isActive: true
  },
  {
    name: 'item3',
    isActive: false
  },
  {
    name: 'item4',
    isActive: true
  }
];
export default data;
```

I use this data in multiple component :

**Component1**

```
export class C1Component {
  items: IItem [] = items;
}
```

**Component1**

```
export class C2Component {
  items: IItem [] = items;
}
```

When I make changes in the items for example delete item in Component1, the items in the other component also changed.
I can't understand why.

Does angular Objects are loosely coupled? and how can solve this issue please.

---

I tried also:

```
...
export class Menu {
  static get data() {
    return data;
  }
}
```

and call `Menu.data`, but the error persist and it is the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Changing code position solve my issue, so all I do was to create a class with a get method like this:

```
export class ItemClass {
  static get data() {
    const data: IItem[] = [
      {
        name: 'item1',
        isActive: true
      },
      {
        name: 'item2',
        isActive: true
      },
      {
        name: 'item3',
        isActive: false
      },
      {
        name: 'item4',
        isActive: true
      }
    ];
    return data;
  }
}
```

and in the component I call `items = ItemClass.data;`

Comment: Ok the static getter is the persistence layer. Are you saying this design works when other components make changes? If it does then using getter logic returns by value and not reference.

Comment: @JohnPeters Yes this logic work with me. but I try to understand your answer, as a new in angular there are many things unclear for me

Answer (score 0):

Javascript use reference and not value when you pass variable in your component.
So if you don't want to alter your "items" array element, you must copy it before using.
Like this :

```
export class C1Component {
  items: IItem [] = [...items];
}

export class C2Component {
  items: IItem [] = [...items];
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer, do you suggest to duplicate `const data: IItem[]` in all components? this data contains hundreds of items, so if I duplicate them in my components it will be ugly, and not maintainable

Comment: if you don't want that C1Component modify items data for C2Component you have no other solutions that duplcate the array.

Comment:        , this is really bad way, and I want to avoid it, thank you any way, I will wait for other solutions :D

Comment: I found a solution for my issue :)

Comment: It will be nice to share your solution :)